# How to simplify this JavaScript/Angular code?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, angular, ternary

`aria-describedby` needs to have a space between multiple IDs. `aria-describedby` needs to be taken out from `<div>` attributes when it's not needed.

I've tried this, which is working fine, but my supervisor is not happy; he wants me to simplify it using array and I have no idea where to start:

```js
var describedByText = [this.error ? this.errorId : '', this.help ? this.helpId : '' ];
var describedBy = describedByText.join(" ");
```

Then in HTML `<div>`, I have this:

```html
aria-describedby=“${ifDefined(describedBy ? describedBy : undefined)}”
```

The result when there are multiple IDs is:

```html
<div aria-describedby="FormId1 FormId2"></div>
```

where `aria-describedby` is not needed:

```html
<div aria-describedby=" "></div> <!-- which should be <div></div> -->
```

Answer (score 0):

Even when one of `this.errorId` or `this.helpId` are not set, you still always add two elements to the array. `Array.prototype.join` doesn't care what these elements actually are and simply joins them and puts a space between them.

Therefore you end up with `describedBy === ' '`.

To fix this, only add an element to the array when you have to:

```js
var describedByText = [];

if (this.errorId) {
    describedByText.push(this.errorId);
}

if (this.helpId) {
    describedByText.push(this.helpId);
}

var describedBy = describedByText.join(" ");
```

Answer (score 0):

Regarding taking `aria-describedby` out of the **div**, you can do something like this:

```
<div [attr.aria-describedby]="describedBy || null"></div>
```

Use attribute binding for your ARIA attribute and set it's value depending on a `describedBy` value. Set the attribute value as `null` if `describedBy` is an empty string - this will remove the attribute from the DOM.